# jQuery(selector) vs. $(selector)

Tags: jquery

Why is it that in wp-admin/js/updates.js (in Wordpress 4.2) `$(selector)` is used but in wp-admin/incldes/file.php `jQuery(selector)` is used? Is there a particular reason for this or is it just an oversight on the part of the development team?

Comment: Check out [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).  It's a combination of personal preference and "needs" on when the script can be (should be) executed.  (such as when DOM is fully loaded or not)

Comment: @josh That's pretty much the answer - post it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of jQuery noConflict wrappers.  It is certainly not an oversight by WordPress developers; but rather, a great little way to ensure we (developers) can hook our own javascript files or libraries without conflicting with other javascript code.

Be sure to read the [Codex on jQuery noConflict Wrappers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

The usage pretty much depends on your intentions; and when you want the script to be executed (when DOM is fully constructed; as opposed to immediately).

It's all explained very well on the codex page linked above.